# Best way to handle file operation for Logging last 1000 Events

Tags: c++, algorithm, file

I came across a situation where I have to log last 1000 events present in the queue.
What will be the best solution to handle this by reducing costly file operation?
At present we are completely rewriting the file with all the queue entries.

Out of the two solutions mentioned below, which one is good? or is there any other option to speed up the logging?

1. Making a fixed log message size and using file pointer do read/write operation.
2. Creating multiple files and when the request comes, then read 1000 events from last files

Comment: Does the file name have to stay the same?  Is it okay if you log up to the lass 2000 events?

Comment: There is no constraint regarding file name. Only thing is when the user request we have to provide last 1000 event logs. We are storing 1000 events for reloading it, when the application restarts.

Comment: does it matter if the log file becomes large? if now, simply tail -1000 <logfile> from a terminal

Comment: Is it specifically required that logging involve writing to a file?   Could, for example, there be a second program running that manages a FIFO queue, and exposes an API for use by your program that needs the logging service?   That second program could also respond to events/signals, such as a request to dump events to a file on request, or on some fixed time interval.

Comment: One though would be to have 2 files.  One full log file and one builder file.  Once the builder hits 1000 events then delete to log file and rename the builder to the log file.  Then start a new builder.  At most you will have 1999 entries.

Comment: Can you offload the file-writing to a separate thread?

Comment: You could use Redis and `LPUSH` to push items on a list with occasional `LTRIM`s to prune down to the last 1000 items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several considerations here, that can't be all simultaneously optimized. Among them are:

1. the latency and throughput of the process emitting the logging messages
2. the total number of IO operations
3. the latency of reading log messages

There probably is no "best way". You need to find a working point that suits your requirements.

---

For example, Nathan Oliver basically suggested in the comments to have the emitting process writing to some `aux` file, and once it is full to have it rename `aux` to `log`.

This idea has very low latency characteristics for the emitter, and an essentially optimal total number of IO ops. Conversely, (at least depending on the implementation,) it has unbounded latency for the reader. Say the logger emits 1700 messages, then indefinitely stops logging. There is no bound on the time it will take the log reader to access the last 700 messages.

So, this idea might be excellent in some settings, but in other settings it might be considered less adequate.

---

A different way of doing it (with a different working point), is to have the process emitting the messages write again to some `aux`. When either `aux` has a number of messages that exceed some number (possibly less than 1000), or a certain amount of time has passed, it should rename `aux` to some temporary-named file in a `temp` directory.

Meanwhile, a background process can periodically scan the `tmp` directory. When it sees there files, it should read:

- the `log` file (which is the only file viewed externally)
- the files it found in `tmp` sorted by modification time

It should retain the last 1000 messages (at most), write them to some `tmp_log` file, rename it to `log`, and then erase the files it read in `tmp`.

This has reasonable latency for both emitter and reader, but more total IO accesses. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It is very much helpful.